# Sharing set up and tear down methods across multiple selenium projects

Tags: visual-studio, selenium

So, I have multiple selenium test projects in separate VS solutions and they all have the same Setup() methods which are executed before scenarios are run as well as all having the same TearDown() methods for after.  Currently if a change is required for these methods, they have to be updated separately so I was looking in to centralising these methods to be used in all of the test projects/solutions.

I'm relatively new so apologise in advance but does anyone have experience of this with suggestions on approaches I could take?  Is it even possible?  My tests do not currently run in parallel so is this something I'd need to look in to?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just create a function for setup and teardown and then call them from `Setup()` and `TearDown()`? That way everything is centralized in those two functions.

Comment: Hi JeffC.  They are set up like this within the individual projects but unfortunately, at the moment, each test project is in its own solution and it's the sharing of these two functions across projects and solutions that I am trying to achieve.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

How if you change code be 
[OneTimeSetUp] and [OneTimeTearDown]?

in my opinion you should create one class for setup include setup and tear down then in yor test add setup like this public class HREmployeeList:Setup

Hopefully help or not just check this below link
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/how-to-write-selenium-test-using-nunit-framework/

Comment: Hi Yuninda.  I'll take a look in to this to see if there's something I've missed and come back to you as to how it went.  Unfortunately, the test projects are within separate solutions and it is how to share these setup and teardown functions across all projects/solutions.  It may just be that the approach needs to be outright changed but I'd like to know for sure before taking on such a task.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create a new project that contains the functions for setup and teardown and then include that compiled dll in all the other projects. If you need to make a change to setup/teardown, you make the change and compile a new dll and the code change is passed to all the other projects.

Comment: This sounds good @JeffC.  I'm still in the midst of trying this stuff out in amongst other work but I will update asap.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping long story short - you need to create a Meta framework.

> By concept Meta frameworks provide a method of solving the problem with automating multiple pieces as part of a larger automation strategy. Testers define independent utility classes which can be generically used with any automation tool and can be reused between different automation projects as well. The framework provides an abstraction layer that allows the separate automation pieces to be executed and have their results reported back in a standardized way.

I have a [post on the topic](http://automationisking.blogspot.bg/p/hybrid-ui-test-framework.html), so feel free to take what you need form there.

Since you've tagged VisualStudio, I'll share first the approach my team did use for sharing common functionality across Test projects. What you need is a private Nuget server. Each team compiles and supports a Nuget pack based on the service it provides. For example Selenium code, API calls etc.

Next and probably closer to your case solution would be to utilize [git submodules](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/git-submodules-workflows-tips) and share the Test [harness engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness) between your projects.

Both approaches will benefit of a [Fixture Setup Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Setup%20Patterns.html) like Shared Fixture Construction.

Comment: This seems way overly complicated to solve a simple problem like this. Why would you need a private NuGet server, etc. to do this?

Comment: To keep your code private. How would you protect your packages, that you want to share across projects? And this is just one suggestion (more company environment oriented, i agree), that was working for my team back in the days. The other options are also valid, @JeffC if you have better ones - please share and help to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi ekostadinov.  I will look into the information you've provided and let you know.  I know that we won't be able to have a private Nuget server at this stage but I may be able to utilise the current infrastructure in some way.

Comment: In this case, maybe the sub-modules combined w/ the Meta-framework will be a better fit. In any case let's touch base again, once you've made it work. It is interesting discussion, that would benefit others as well. @CharlieBeddoes

Comment: Thank you @ekostadinov, I'll come back to you asap.